# How do the expiration dates on driver licenses not count as an "arbitrary revocation"

Tags: constitutional-law, driving

Driver licensing is ostensibly legally valid based on the following:

> The regulation of the exercise of the right to drive a private
>   automobile on the streets of the city may be accomplished in part by
>   the city by granting, refusing, and revoking under rules of general
>   application permits to drive an automobile on its streets; but such
>   permits may not be arbitrarily refused or revoked, or permitted to be
>   held by some and refused to others of like qualifications, under like
>   circumstances and conditions.

Why are license expiration dates (and associated requirement to pay renewal fees) not considered arbitrary revocations of the license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a rant.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, its a rant but there is a legal question in there.

Comment: It appears that someone who asked a previous question and got badly down voted is now setting up a new userID to follow up. I don't know that this is a TOS violation, but it is concerning.

Comment: @ohwilleke I copied the relevant part of a somewhat related question answer to mine. Sorry for any confusion. I did rant I don't know how not to.

Comment: @Dale M Thank you. I think I did my best to clarify my use of arbitrary vs your use of it if you would be willing to check back and see if what I've written helps clarify. If not at least thank you for being objective in seeing I have a real question even if it is not put together in the best format.

Answer (score 6):

### [Arbitrary](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/arbitrary) doesn't mean what you think it means

> The term arbitrary describes a course of action or a decision that is not based on reason or judgment but on personal will or discretion without regard to rules or standards.

A clear rule that a license fee is required to be paid by a certain date that is the same for everyone is pretty much the opposite of arbitrary.

Comment: Apparently you are the one who does not understand the meanign of arbitrary. I am using the literal definition not the legal one to point out in our common language how silly the concept that a person who IS legally qualified to operate an automobile one day does not in any way LOSE that ability by having a certain amount of time pass. That amount of time being both literally arbitrary and therefore legally arbitrary. 

You say its a law that has requirements and is therefore not arbitrary in a legal way, I say it was created for a literal arbitrary purpose so why are we keeping it around?

Comment: This is not an offense to you. I am drawing from this specific case as I feel it is the most relevant here. I am not discussing the validity of licensing. I am pointing out that provisions for licensing specify that the manner we are going about it may be incorrect. 

Please answer my question for real. You insist this is a 'frivolous argument' you provide no sources for this claim.

If I am right in concept and we change the law to reflect it no one will ever have to pay for a license past the first issuance. Leading into [another time] not having any recurring fees of any kind.

Comment: @TiaLiebe you need to consult a dictionary, any dictionary- there is no legal definition of arbitrary that is different from the common English one.

Comment: "A clear rule that a license fee is required to be paid by a certain date that is the same for everyone is pretty much the opposite of arbitrary."

The expiration date existing in the first place is the definition of arbitrarily revoking a valid license.

Please if you disagree clearly explain how voiding your license simply after a certain amount of time forcing you to pay for another is anything BUT arbitrary.

Which if I read correctly is a violation of how licensing for automobiles can be lawfully carried out.

Comment: Requiring a license exist in perpetuity or for life is no more or less arbitrary than granting them for a fixed term. By the way- licenses “expire” they don’t get “voided”. The existence or not of the license doesn’t affect your *ability* to drive, just the legality of it.

Comment: How? It protects from incapable people legally operating vehicles until proven in attendance of a state worker the cost of which is covered by the fee to take the test.

You say "The existence or not of the license doesn’t affect your ability to drive, just the legality of it."

This is my entire point. So why make it more costly than it needs to be?

If someone passed a test that the state is allowed to put into place to get a license [proof they CAN drive] which then unlocks the privilege.
Why should that ever expire? OR if it is expiring for a reason why remedy with cash?

Comment: Do you get what I'm asking?

Why is it paying a fee or not that 'determines' your legality of driving if the entire premise of having the law on the books in the first place is keeping people safe?

Either there shouldn't be recurring fees OR there should be recurring TESTS to validate the fees.

Does paying this fee to keep a valid license provide any actual service to either the person paying the fee or the rest of the citizens who will be exposed to the individuals driving once the fee is paid?

Does taking a test every few years add extra protection in exchange for that fee?

Comment: Sorry I'm working with a character limit with a question that requires so much more than I can say at one time to have a real discussion about.

Comment: You say "Requiring a license exist in perpetuity or for life is no more or less arbitrary than granting them for a fixed term. By the way- licenses “expire” they don’t get “voided”. The existence or not of the license doesn’t affect your ability to drive, just the legality of it."

Comment: Im saying treat licenses like diplomas. Pay to get them but good for life. This would save everyone money.

You respond with 'who cares its no more or less arbitrary than the other way'

I respond with 'Why choose the more expensive and restrictive of the two if there is no difference in /how/ arbitrary they are?

Should we be making people pay colleges a recurring fee to continue to validate their diplomas?
Diplomas are just a vital for life in this modern world as motorised transportation.

Comment: @TiaLiebe First, Stack Exchange is not meant to be a discussion forum. Second, if you want, think of the license fee as an excise tax on driving. Raising revenue is a legitimate government interest; restricting the operation of vehicles on public (tax-funded!) roads to people who have paid a fee is a perfectly sensible way to raise revenue.

Comment: @cpast what is the point of getting a question answered if you can't use that answer to lead into your next question on the subject? Maybe I really don't understand the point of this site at all, I thought it was meant to be used to ask questions?

Comment: @TiaLiebe Each question is meant to be a single question, with the answers being answers to that single question. Follow-up questions, unless they're very closely related (like "do you know if this rule is IL-specific or is common nationwide"), should be asked as separate questions. It isn't meant to support a drawn-out discussion at all; in fact, the site is specifically designed to discourage that sort of thing.

Comment: @cpast There is already an excise tax on driving directed at the actual individuals who deserve to pay it.

This is not what the fee's purpose is. The fee's purpose is to keep your license valid. My question is how [fully described process and references] does the state who is unable to refuse a license to similarly qualified persons and also unable to arbitrarily revoke that license legally explain how they can both A refuse a license to someone who will not pay an upkeep fee and B revoke one person's license because a few minutes on a clock are different when previously they were valid.

Comment: @cpast I guess I will overlook my question and feedback and come up with a better question. Do you know of a site that is more discussion friendly?

Comment: @TiaLiebe, despite your obvious reluctance to learn anything and/or your rude trolling, I'll nonetheless say, this is just so simple: arbitrary means random. According to Wikipedia, nobody's definition of "legal" even though there is no such thing as a "legal definition of arbitrary" and a "literal definition of arbitrary," the word arbitrariness "is the quality of being 'determined by chance, whim, or impulse, and not by necessity, reason, or principle." Therefore, even if it is simply because they want to make money to maintain the roads, it's legitimate, and by no definition, arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about where governments get the authority to require licenses, the answer is that it's inherent in their status as governments. In the United States, the federal government is one of enumerated powers. When Congress passes a law, and that law is challenged, the government has to be able to point to a specific section of the Constitution that the law is implementing.

This limitation is specific to the US federal government, and is a result of the federal-state distribution of powers. It is *not* a general requirement that all governments have to abide by. Generically, governments have full authority to pass laws on any subject in order to promote the general welfare unless there's some reason they *can't* pass it. This is called "general police power," and in the US it is possessed by the states. There are some limits to what state governments can do, to be sure. They can't interfere with federal law in areas regulated by the federal government. They can't pass a law that names an individual and punishes them. They can't infringe on fundamental rights protected by the federal constitution. Their state constitution imposes its own limits on what they can't do. But that's how it's expressed -- in terms of what they *can't* do. The idea that they can do anything to promote the public welfare unless there's some reason to say otherwise is implicit.

In this case, unless there is an actual reason states *can't* require paying a regular fee to drive on public roads, they are allowed to do it. States have the inherent power to raise revenue. An excise tax on operating an automobile on tax-funded streets (which is what a license fee amounts to, with an unexpired license serving as proof of payment) is a perfectly legitimate way of raising revenue, just like imposing a toll to use a particular street is a perfectly legitimate way of raising revenue.

You're claiming it's arbitrary because the specific amount of the fee and how long it lasts for are arbitrary, but almost everything government does is arbitrary in that sense. Maryland requires 20/40 vision for an unrestricted license. Is someone with 20/41 vision significantly less able to drive than someone with 20/40? Nope. However, there's certainly a good reason to say "you must have decent vision to drive." Letting examiners make their own judgment calls on whether vision means whether you pass can depend on how your examiner is feeling that day. *This* is the kind of arbitrariness that a government is supposed to minimize: an individual has no idea whether an examiner will say their vision is good enough or not, and there's no standard to ensure people are treated equally. By setting the line at 20/40, there is a single rule applicable to every state resident. You might be denying someone a license because their vision is only slightly worse than the arbitrary standard, but that's better than leaving this totally up to an individual examiner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

You are mostly on the same page as me so far.

So to follow up with my next question. How do I start to change this system? I insist that in its current state it makes no real sense to have a valid license one day proving you know how to operate a vehicle suddenly become invalid the next legally implying you no longer know how to drive. 

I personally see no reason to continue to support this system as it is as I see no way it provides any protections or benefits to anyone participating in it. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You say "imposing a toll to use a particular street is a perfectly legitimate way of raising revenue"

This is not a valid way to raise revenue. All citizens have the right to utilize the post roads that must be maintained by our government. No citizen is required to pay any fee to exercise their right to travel on our public highways. Private roads not included.

Comment: You say "there's certainly a good reason to say "you must have decent vision to drive.""

yes there is and I understand the concept of arbitrary as a literal vs legal context.

I am saying that because having an expiration date on a skill that does not expire is literally arbitrary. The opposite of having a number associated with the vision test. That we should be rethinking the law as written.

It would be more socially inclusive and less economically intrusive if we made liscenses a one time buy UNLESS they are voided/suspended/;w/e legal wording you want to use for it.

Comment: I'm saying by definition the vision requirment in not arbitrary. Why were these numbers chosen? I bet an eye doctor can answer how they came up with the numbers in a non arbitrary way.

On to the 'it expires unless you pay a fee' part.
How and why was the existence of an expiration date that will force a monetary encumbrance onto the citizen in question not decided to be included arbitrarily? Where is the motivation for all the citizens representatives to have voted this into law? Where is the REASON and JUDGMENT used to determine that expiration dates of licensing have a legit purpose.

Comment: The eye test benefits us in keeping blind people from driving cars.
The initial fees provide for the license creation and keeping the database up to date.

Who and in what way does the expiration date benefit? Does it provide extra security? No. Does it help keep criminals off the streets? No. Does it make driving a car safer? No. Does it arbitrarily convert an activity that the day previous was perfectly legal and probably required for your daily life into a crime for you to do the following day that you may now have to incur more personal financial loss just to /continue/ your life.